# Django-south not detecting DB changes

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have updated our project from svn and I have new migration files.
When I use :

```
./work/manage.py schemamigration mypackage --auto
```

I have this message:

```
Nothing seems to have changed.
```

But the database has changed! Why south couldn't detect any change?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the migration files, there is no need to run `schemamigration` as that just generates the migration files. To apply the migration files to the database, run:

```
./work/manage.py migrate mypackage --merge
```

The `merge` flag will run any missed migrations as a result of an SVN update.