# South - Not detecting changes to Django model

Tags: django, django-south

I have Django model that I already have initialized with south using `./manage.py schemamigration (appname) --initial`. All was going well through this point, until I decided I needed another field. I added another field and tried to to migrate the change with `./manage.py schemamigration (appname) --auto`, but it says:

```
- Nothing to migrate.
```

I made sure to migrate the initial changes.
Seems to be similar to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635492/django-south-not-detecting-db-changes), but the solution got me nowhere.

Comment: did you by any chance create the initial migration after adding the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because between the `--initial` migration and the next `schemamigration` you have to persist the **actual migration** to the db issuing the command `python manage.py migrate my_app`.

After doing that first migration then you may add another field, do and `schemamigration --auto`  and commit it to the db again by doing `python manage.py migrate my_app`

Hope this helps!